# can't see number of votes on accepted answer in user pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The small boxes on user pages that are supposed to show the number of votes just show blank green squares for me if the answer was accepted. Like this:
[image]

In case it matters, I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.